# Glitchy Shadow effect

Tags: modeling

Just interested in why this happens. I'll be modelling and after some time the shadow decides to go horrible. A restart fixes it but I'd rather find a fix.

Windows, Blender 3.6.7 LTS, Ryzen 7 5800x, RX 6900XT

[Video of problem]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UI1VHGOeKs

Not a z-fight, these are all single entities.

(The answer below about the clipping is correct, I alter it when in edit mode when close up to a vertex and it's (invisible) clipping. I change it so I can see it, but never knew it the result would cause this)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello check if you don't have a copy of your object or faces overlapping, or please share your file

Comment: +1 moonboots ... looks like z-fight.

Comment: I will keep that in mind Duarte, thanks for your input.

Comment: I should of made clear it was not a Z-fight. My bad for not clarifying that in the post. I will update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and increase the Clip Start value or the End value from the View tab on the N-Panel.
Sometimes if the object too small or too big you might encounter these artifacts.
[image: view tab n_panel]